# Issue when transposing a matrix twice

Tags: c++, matrix

So i want to transpose a matrix and it works fine , but when i try to transpose it again it gives me the transposed matrix and underneath it the original and i just can't figure  out why? Maybe my algorithm is wrong, but i don;t see the flaw in it.

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int red=100;
const int col=100;
int main ()
{
int n,m,i,j,x;
cin>>n>>m;
char p;

int a[red][col],b[red][col],c[red][col];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
{
    cin>>a[i][j];
}
cin>>p;
while(p=='t'){
if(n<m){
  for(i=0;i<m;i++){
for(j=0;j<m;j++)

{
    b[i][j]=a[j][i];
}}
x=m;
m=n;
n=x;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
{
    c[i][j]=b[i][j];
    a[i][j]=c[i][j];
    cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;}}

if(n>m){
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
for(j=0;j<n;j++)

{
    b[i][j]=a[j][i];
}}
x=m;
m=n;
n=x;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
{    c[i][j]=b[i][j];
     a[i][j]=c[i][j];
    cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;}}
if(n==m)
   {for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<m;j++)

{
    b[i][j]=a[j][i];
}
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
{    c[i][j]=b[i][j];
     a[i][j]=c[i][j];
    cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;}}
cin>>p;}


}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Also, please indent your code properly, as it is now, it's unreadable.

Comment: I haven't looked over your code, but... transposing a matrix and then transposing it again.. it gives the original matrix...

Comment: "Where is my mistake" - for starters, your title isn't descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

This code is pretty-much unmaintainable. Begin by putting some work into making it clean and clear.

Put the code that transposes the matrix into a separate function. Put the code that shows the contents of the matrix into a separate function. Put the code that sets the value of the matrix into a separate function. Write `main` so that it calls the appropriate functions in the appropriate order.